# How to sort an array, which most common element at first?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

for example, suppose I have an array : [3,2,2,1,4,5,3,2,2,1,1], which I want to sort into this form:

```
[2,2,2,2,1,1,1,3,3,4,5]
```

which 2 is the most common element, then 1 and so on,how can I write a sort function:

```
let arr=[3,2,2,1,4,5,3,2,2,1,1];
arr.sort(function(p0,p1){
  //how to write it?
});
```

to do that?

I tried:

```
 let arr=[3,2,2,1,4,5,3,2,2,1,1];
 let numPosMap=new Map();
 for(let i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
     let num=arr[i];
     if(!numPosMap[num]){
         numPosMap[num]=[];
     }
     numPosMap[num].push(i);
 }
 let posArrayArray=[];
 for(let num in numPosMap) {
     posArrayArray.push(numPosMap[num]);
 }
 posArrayArray.sort(function(a,b){
   return a.length<b.length;
 });

 let resultArr=[];
 for(let posArray of posArrayArray){
   for(let pos of posArray){
     resultArr.push(pos);
   }
 }
```

which has many lines of codes, is there any simpler method?

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include [any attempt](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific problem you're having in a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My recommendation would be to create another object that counts how many of each element appear in your array. Once you have that, you can sort just by comparing the quantity of each element.

Example:

```js
let arr = [3, 2, 2, 1, 4, 5, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1];

// Do some preprocessing first...
let counts = arr.reduce((counts, num) => {
  counts[num] = (counts[num] || 0) + 1;
  return counts;
}, {});

console.log(counts);

arr.sort(function(p0,p1){
  return counts[p1] - counts[p0];
});

console.log(arr);
```